# App exporting to SD card

Tags: applications

I remember android has disabled app exporting to SD card since i dont remember which version, but a person has showed me his 7.0 or 7.4 LG which actually is able to move apps to SD card. Why is this happening and how can i do the same at 7.0 androd? Preferably, without having to format SD card as internal storage

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about formatting as internal storage, if your device can read it, it's already formatted for Android, and can be used as either internal or external... just switch it.

Also, some applications don't allow moving the app for compatibility and security reasons, it's not always device dependent.

Try scrolling through the apps and see if you can move any of them across.

Comment: Thank you, well, i remember many apps just as facebook or whatsapp were able to be moved in old android versions. And these apps still be transferable at this date while android is an older version. Why would these companies disable this on newest releases? Any of my strongest apps are  movable to SD card so im starting to be suspicious about the android's version

Comment: I'm not sure on the small details as to why, but while developing apps for my own projects, some permission usage's ( the method i used ) requires android:installLocation="InternalOnly" to have access to specific data on the internal storage, if you don't have this in the manifest the application crashes... I gather it's something to do with restricted folder access on a per-app basis.

Comment: I understand now, its more like a logistical error which has not been handled by the devs which causes: A) New permissions engine requires internal only manifiests B) Attempting a portable to SD app pushes you to not ask for permissions, which makes the app obsolete C) You have to choose between obsolete or internal only, so the most of the devs actually prefer to manifiest internal only for logics. Have i understood well Zillinium....?

Comment: I'll agree with that. . It's more complicated than that, but basically the same results, permission failures etc...